# expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'MLD_PACKET'

Tags: c++, c

Wherever I include a certain `commands.h` header file, in any place apart from `commands.c`, this error is thrown up by the compiler. `commands.h` contains function prototypes which make use of structs defined in `instrument.h`, specifically:

```
void readConfig(PSTATPLUS_CONFIG* pStatConfig_p, MLD_PACKET* rxPacketUart2_p);
void readState(PSTATPLUS_STATE* pStatState_p, MLD_PACKET* rxPacketUart2_p);
void writeConfig(PSTATPLUS_CONFIG* pStatConfig_p, MLD_PACKET* rxPacketUart2_p);
void writeState(PSTATPLUS_STATE* pStatState_p, MLD_PACKET* rxPacketUart2_p);
```

`PSTATPLUS_CONFIG` and `PSTATPLUS_STATE` are defined as such, in `instrument.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    float signalAmplitude;      // Signal Amplitude
    float signalOffset;         // Signal Offset
    unsigned char waveType;     // Waveform Type
    float startFreq;            // Frequency Start
    float stopFreq;             // Frequency Stop
    unsigned int numIncrements; // Number of Increments
    unsigned char scale;        // Linear(0) or log(1)
    float stepDelay;            // Step Delay
}PSTATPLUS_CONFIG;

typedef struct {    // Current biosensor status
    unsigned char scan;     // Scan status (on/off)
    unsigned char sample;   // Sample status (on/off)
    unsigned int currentIncrement; // Current scan increment
    unsigned char gain;     // Current gain setting
    float iValue;           // I voltage
    float qValue;           // Q voltage
    unsigned int sampleDivider; // 1 takes every ADC sample, 2 takes every 2nd ADC sample, 3 takes every 3rd ADC samp... n takes every nth. 0 stops data collection.
    unsigned int totalSamples;  // total number of samples wanted to complete one measurement.
}PSTATPLUS_STATE;
```

I require some definitions written in the `commands.h` header to be accessible to my `instrument.c` file but as mentioned, every time I include `commands.h` in there, the compiler produces that error. I've tried including `commands.h` in some of my other source files, the same thing keeps happening. Any help is appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Where is MLD_PACKET defined?

Comment: Looks like you'll need either to include the header where `MLD_PACKET` is declared in your `commands.h`, or have a forward declaration for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your commands.h `#include "instrument.h"` since it needs things in there otherwise `PSTATPLUS_CONFIG` or `PSTATPLUS_STATE` will cause errors.

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_INCLUDED
#define COMMANDS_INCLUDED

#include "instrument.h"

//.. as you were

#endif
```

Comment: Thing is, that header was fine without including instrument.h. As insane as this sounds, I now cannot re-create the problem. I can include commands.h into instrument.c and no errors are created =/

Comment: If you #included "instrument.h" then #included "commands.h" in the instrument.cpp it might have worked there - you need to see the definitions before you use them, or as a half way house forward declare in the header, and then make sure you have the definition to hand where you use stuff

Answer (score 0):

It looks like compiler thinks MLD_PACKET is an argument not type. You should also include the definition or declaration of it before you use it. Forward declare it at the least.